# Producing raster mosaic dataset using spatial query on another mosaic in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, mosaic, mosaic-dataset

Using ArcGIS 10.1 (Build 3143) I would like to create a relatively small raster mosaic dataset (the size of a city) based on a larger, existing one (the size of a state) using a single feature class polygon as a spatial query.  Is this possible?

Clipping the raster mosaic with Clip (Data Management Tools > Raster > Raster Processing > Clip) or Extract by Mask (Spatial Analyst Tools > Extraction > Extract by Mask) produce low-resolution rasters instead of mosaics.

Over the past few weeks I think I remember seeing the option to perform the operation described above, but now I cannot find it.  Ultimately, I will publish the raster mosaic dataset in ArcGIS Server.

Comment: Described another way, is it possible to restrict the display of a raster mosaic dataset to only the part that falls inside of a feature polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Create Referenced Mosaic Dataset ([10.1 docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Create_Referenced_Mosaic_Dataset/00170000008p000000/)) to do what you're requesting. To use a feature class as the filter, include it as the `in_template_dataset`. You can either clip to the feature or use the feature's extent based on how you set `select_using_features`:

- SELECT_USING_FEATURES —The selection is based on the shape of the feature. This is the default.
- NO_SELECT_USING_FEATURES —The selection is based on the extent of the data within the feature class.

Comment: Thanks!  I just tested it on a time-enable, derived raster mosaic built from 4 years of imagery of the state of Kentucky.  Create Referenced Mosaic Dataset successfully isolates the area of interest without showing imagery beyond the extent of the feature polygon.